# How to test for Case-Insensitive StringA.Contains(StringB)?

Tags: c#, string

How can I test whether a substring is contained in other, but case-insensitively?

`string1.Contains(string2)` is not case insensitive. if there is no existing method, I would want to write a optimized method, any pointer for that?

**Edit:** It should also work with globalization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert both strings to upper case before performing the check:

```
string1.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(string2.ToUpperInvariant())
```

Or if you want to take the current culture into account when defining case insesitivity:

```
string1.ToUpper().Contains(string2.ToUpper())
```

Or you could even use a specific culture by calling the `ToUpper` overload that accepts a `CultureInfo`.

The reason that you should convert to upper case and not lower case is described in [code analysis warning CA1308: Normalize strings to uppercase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx):

> Strings should be normalized to uppercase. A small group of characters, when they are converted to lowercase, cannot make a round trip. To make a round trip means to convert the characters from one locale to another locale that represents character data differently, and then to accurately retrieve the original characters from the converted characters.

You may wonder what "small group of characters" are affected by this and apparently at least some Georgian scripts have this problem according to [Michael S. Kaplan](http://www.siao2.com/2004/12/02/273619.aspx).

Comment: That will be somewhat culture-insensitive, however. We don't know that's the required type of comparison.

Comment: @JonSkeet what is culture-insensitive? is it something related to globalization support?

Comment: @ay89: Yes. Different strings will be "equal" in a case-insensitive way to different people, based on their culture. Look up the "Turkey test" for particularly tricky examples.

Comment: here, whats the diff between .ToUpperVariant() and ToUpper(CultureInfo) ?

Comment: Since I'm from _Turkey_ this is an example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Comment: @ay89: `ToUpperInvariant` converts to upper case using the _invariant culture_ (`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`) which is based on the "en-US" culture. Upper casing the letter __i__ will result in __I__. Using `ToUpper(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR"))` will result in __İ__ (Turkish upper case dotted I) as pointed out by Soner Gönül.

Answer (score 4):

Use [String.IndexOf Method (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx)

```
string str = "Some test String";
string str2 = "test";
if (str.IndexOf(str2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0)
{
    //str contains str2
}
else
{
    //str does not contain str2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string1.ToUpper().Contains(string2.ToUpper())
```

Comment: [CA1308: Normalize strings to uppercase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi My haste to answer reversed my logic

Answer (score 2):

You can use this overload of [`String.IndexOf Method (String, StringComparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx)

For `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`

> Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules, the invariant
>   culture, and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.

```
string string1 = "YOURSTRING";
bool containsornot = string1 .IndexOf("yourstring", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/FJ5RHD).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried **string1.IndexOf(string2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)**

or use **StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase**

[click here for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx)

Comment: There is no such argument. -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Comment: [string.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) doesn't have an overload which takes `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Comment: my mistake copied same text